# .Net 5 DateTime.ParseExact problems

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-5, datetime-parsing

Just migrated on .Net 5.
The next code returns "01/01/0001 00:00:00 +00:00" in "date" variable.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    "Июн 16 2021",
    "MMМ d yyyy",
    CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU"),
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out DateTime date
);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/E5VDbH

Facing no problem on .Net Core 3.1.

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Comment: Try printing out all month names. Sometimes they "fix" these.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-5.0#cultureinfo-and-cultural-data .  The `TryParseExact` fails most likely due to how `CultureInfo` is handled differently on .NET Core 3.1 versus .NET 5.

Comment: That is expected because `DateTime.TryParseExact` returns `false` which means the operation did *not* succeed. If you were expecting an `Exception` you need to use the method `DateTime.ParseExact` (without Try). Try means return true/false based on success and do not throw an Exception.

Comment: It works when you change the text to "июнь 16 2021"

Comment: @PMF, thanks for good advice )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went in the same direction as @PMF and printed out all the month names for the `ru-RU` culture. From that I could see that there is no month abbreviation that matches what you have in your example. Here's how to get all the valid values:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" - ", ci.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames));
```

Seeing as we're in June I suspect `Июн` is also supposed to be June, which in .NET 5 is abbreviated as `июнь`.

I don't read or write Russian so I don't know how these compare to what *you're* expecting, but that's at least what .NET 5 is expecting.

When I replaced `Июн` with `июнь` in your example it correctly parsed it as a date.

You could've seen this if you had used `DateTime.ParseExact()` and surrounded your code in a `try/catch`. You would've got an exception that told you:

> String 'Июн 16 2021' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Which could've pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

It's a breaking change in .NET 5 where [Globalization APIs use ICU libraries on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api). To keep the old behaviour, [you can add the following to the .csproj file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/globalization-icu#use-nls-instead-of-icu)

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Other options are set the "System.Globalization.UseNls" on the runtimeconfig.json

```json
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
     "configProperties": {
       "System.Globalization.UseNls": true
      }
  }
}
```

or setting the environment variable `DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_USENLS` to `true` or `1`.